# Require mdbootstrap through webpacker 4 fails

Tags: webpack-4, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6, mdbootstrap

When I require mdbootrstrap in a webpacker pack, the following error is outputed:

- Firefox: `TypeError: "exports" is read-only`
- Chrome: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'`

Is there a config tweak that I could make to get rid of this error? Or must I just wait for mdbootstrap owner to release a patch for this?

Any help appreciated!

Links:

- Github demo app: https://github.com/yoones/rails_6_mdb_through_webpacker
- Yarn `package.json`: https://github.com/yoones/rails_6_mdb_through_webpacker/blob/master/package.json
- Webpacker env config: https://github.com/yoones/rails_6_mdb_through_webpacker/blob/master/config/webpack/environment.js
- Webpacker pack: https://github.com/yoones/rails_6_mdb_through_webpacker/blob/master/app/javascript/packs/application.js

Versions:

- Ruby on Rails 6.0.1
- Webpacker 4.2.2
- mdbootstrap 4.10.1

Comment: I looked at bit at mdbootstrap and it just doesn't look very Webpack-friendly as of 4.10.

Comment: I see you posted an issue on their Github site (thank you for doing that!) at https://github.com/mdbootstrap/bootstrap-material-design/issues/268 and just wanted to have that link here so that others can know that it's reported and check its status. It's been almost 8 months now!